# Is secure to ignore the missing dependencies es-lint warning on react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have a component which needs to call a function when is unmounted. This function is passed as a `prop` of the component. As far as I know, to call a function on component unmount you only need a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => { prop.onUnmount() }

}, []);
```

This works as expected, however ESLint complains about a missing dependency on the hook:

> Line 156:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.onUnmount'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

However, neither solutions works,

- If I remove the dependency array, the hook will be executed on each re render
- If add the dependency, despite of `prop.onUnmount()` does not change on any rerender and the hook should not be triggered, it stills executing the `return` part. So the function gets called before the unmount.

So, is it safe to ignore the warning or is there any work around to execute the function and prevent ESLint to warn about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => { prop.onUnmount() }
}, []);
```

This will run the prop.onUnmount function that existed on the very **first** render. So if that prop changes during the life of the component, your code will ignore that change, which is what the lint rule is warning you about.

If you want to run the prop.onUnmount that exists on the **last** render, then you'll need to do the following:

```
const cleanup = useRef();
// update the ref each render so if it changes the newest
//   one will be used during unmount
cleanup.current = prop.onUnmount;
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    cleanup.current();
  }
}, []);
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you may want to extract it to a custom hook, as in:

```
export const useUnmount = (fn) => {
  const fnRef = useRef();
  fnRef.current = fn;
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      fnRef.current();
    }
  }, []);
};

// used like: 
useUnmount(props.onUnmount);
```

Comment: The answer is selected as the correct one but it is not resolving the OP question. The question is if it's secure or not to remove from the linter the warning, not how to handle the situation. If someone needs the render just once time then it will use an empty [], that depends on everyones need.